# Variable changing value at each function call

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

In my chart, I used the code to the value in the x:

```
xAxis: {
                labels: {
                    formatter: function () {
                        if (this.value % 131 == 0) {
                            var newdd = xData;
                            newdd.setSeconds(+(this.value / 131));
                            var mostra = newdd.getHours() + ":" + newdd.getMinutes() + ":" + newdd.getSeconds();

                            newdd.setSeconds(-(this.value / 131));
                            return mostra;
                        } else {
                            return ""
                        }
                    }
                },
            },
```

where the variable XDATA I declared out, but that happens every time it processes the function it changes the value.

you can make sure that it does not change the value? I'm eating the brain to keep it constant!

Thank you in advance...
dave

Comment: var newdd = xData , So xData is changing depending on you if condition .Do you want to keep it constant? irrespective of if condition?

Answer (score 2):

I guess xData is an object?

when you do `var newdd = xData;` you are not copying the data from one ariable to the other, you are creating a reference, if you want to clone the object, you can use `clone` method from jquery

this should solve your problem:

```
var newdd = xData.clone();
```

Please check out more on https://api.jquery.com/clone/